# JSF Primefaces Validation across dialogs with specific area

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

**I have two dialog in form**

```
<h:form id="main">
<p:messages id="msgs" />
<p:dialog header="Dialog 1" >

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="PG1" >
            <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="name" />
            <p:inputText required="true" id="name" value="#{myBean.name}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Age" for="age"/>
            <p:inputText required="true" id="age" value="#{myBean.age}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Add1" ajax="false" validateClient="true" actionListener="#{myBean.Add1}"/>
        <p:commandButton ajax="true" value="Open PG2" onclick="PG2.show()" immediate="true" />

</p:dialog>
<p:dialog header="Dialog 2" >

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="PG2" >
            <p:outputLabel value="House" for="house" />
            <p:inputText required="true" id="house" value="#{myBean.house}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Street" for="street"/>
            <p:inputText required="true" id="street" value="#{myBean.street}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Add2" ajax="false" validateClient="true" actionListener="#{myBean.Add2}"/>

</p:dialog>

</h:form>
```

When I open the second dialog , and Press "Add2" button. it validate the "Dialog 1" elements. I want to validate the "Dialog 2" elements only when Press "Add2" button, not all elements in the form.

Any update!!

Comment: Add process="PG1" in Add1 button and remove ajax ="false". Add process="PG2" IN Add2 button and remove ajax="false".

Comment: You already indirectly gave the answer yourself: just give each dialog its own form.

Comment: Thanks BalusC and MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar